# How can I force a Windows scheduled job to run as an Administrator

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

When executing the batch file interactively in the "run as an administrator" mode, .bat performs as expected.

However, when running it using Windows Scheduler, it appears to be lacking permissions.

Tried the following with lo luck:

- "run with the highest privileges" - in the scheduled job properties
- make sched. job owned by the local service account, local Administrator account etc
- run a shortcut to the .bat instead, which is set to execute under Administrative account in shortcut's properties

whoami /all - during scheduled run - reports that High Mandatory Level group is associated with the .bat

Any ideas how this can be enforced in the Scheduler / scheduled job?

==========================================================

**EDIT @Harry Johnston**

Output of whoami /all:

```
USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name                SID                                           
======================== ==============================================
server1\local-admin S-1-5-21-2412003395-1771022845-1738666672-1000


GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------

Group Name                                                    Type             SID          Attributes                                                     
============================================================= ================ ============ ===============================================================
Everyone                                                      Well-known group S-1-1-0      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
NT AUTHORITY\Local account and member of Administrators group Well-known group S-1-5-114    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
BUILTIN\Administrators                                        Alias            S-1-5-32-544 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Group owner
BUILTIN\Users                                                 Alias            S-1-5-32-545 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
NT AUTHORITY\BATCH                                            Well-known group S-1-5-3      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
CONSOLE LOGON                                                 Well-known group S-1-2-1      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users                              Well-known group S-1-5-11     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization                                Well-known group S-1-5-15     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
NT AUTHORITY\Local account                                    Well-known group S-1-5-113    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
LOCAL                                                         Well-known group S-1-2-0      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication                              Well-known group S-1-5-64-10  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level                          Label            S-1-16-12288 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
```

Comment: Please post the output of `whoami /all` from the scheduled run (with "run with the highest privileges") turned on.

Comment: output in the EDIT section of the OPost

Comment: As I suspected, the batch file is in fact running with administrator privilege.  Whatever your problem is, that's not it.